# FolioReader-Android Cache Issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio, epub

I wanna use the FolioReader-Android library in my Android Studio.
I implement the library on my Gradle and when I want to run the project there is an unknown error:
*

> /Users/hamid/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/1ef74cdf85927d9b084bf9bd34edc7d8/folioreader-0.5.4/res/layout/progress_dialog.xml:13:
>   AAPT: error: resource android:attr/android:progressBarStyle not found.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your gradle dependencies try adding this

```
implementation "com.folioreader:folioreader:0.5.4"
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' // ( for androidx)
configurations.matching { it.name == '_internal_aapt2_binary' }.all {
    config ->
        config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
            details -> details.useVersion("3.3.2-5309881")
        }

}
```

`

Comment: Please try to be more descriptive about the error and how your answer will solve it. Soft suggestion.